# Laravel relationship query optimization

Tags: php, laravel, orm

First of all I apologise for the title, I could not find anything better.

In my project I have Users and Groups. Users can join a group and create a group. The relationships are defined as follows.

**User Model**

```
/** Get all the groups the user is administrator of
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function groupsAdmin()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Group','group_admin_id','id');
}
```

**Group Model**

```
/** Get the users in a group
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\User::class,'groups_users', 'group_id','user_id');
}
```

What I am trying to do is get all the users who have joined the groups created by an user. For that I have written a method in my User model:

```
/**
 * Returns all the users who have attended groups created by this user
 */
public function getPastGroupAttendees()
{
    // first verify if the user is admin of any group
    if(!$this->groupsAdmin)
    {
        return false;
    }

    $attendees = array();

    foreach($this->groupsAdmin as $group)
    {
        if(count($group->users) > 0) $attendees[] = $group->users;
    }
    return $attendees;

}
```

But the problem with this method is its slow and will get slower with new data. And also as a user can join multiple groups, I would get duplicate users from this method. 
So if anyone can show me some directions to optimize and correct this it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup two relations in `User` model:

```
public function groupsAdmin()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Group', 'group_admin_id', 'id');
}

public function groups()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group');
}
```

It's one-to-many for admin and many-to-many for groups and users (you'll need pivot table here).

To load the data, use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
$groupWithUsers = Group::where('group_admin_id', $adminId)->with('users')->first();
$groupsOfUsers = User::with('groups')->get();
```

To remove duplicates you can iterate over groups and [`merge()`](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-merge) all users collections into one and then use [`unique()`](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-unique) method to remove duplicates.

Another way to do it is to create model for pivot table and get all users of the group with simple and readable code:

```
$groups = Group::where('group_admin_id', $adminId)->pluck('id'); // Get IDs of groups.
UserGroup::whereIn('group_id', $groups)->get()->unique(); // Get unique users from these groups.
```

Comment: Thanks, This way the loading time got faster, but still has the duplicate user issue. For example, an user has joined two groups created by me. So I would get that user two times for two groups. I can loop through the record and remove any users who is listed twice, but would that be efficient??

Comment: Thank you very much. I went with your first solution `merge()` and `unique()` .